# How to make a class's function default

Tags: c++, class, arduino

Example code:

```
class Sum{
    public:
        void value(int val){_v = val;}
        int add(int val){return _v + val;}
    private:
        int _v;
};

Sum sum;
sum.value(5);
int myResult = sum.add(10);
```

Is it possible to make the `sum.add(10)` default so I can get the same result like this:

```
int myArea = sum(10);
```

(I suspect the question title is wrong, perhaps it is the reason why I can't find a solution. Feel free to edit.)

Comment: That's what you can override operators for. `+`, `-`, `+=`, `-=`... all those arithmetic operators can be overriden, so you can give them user-defined behavior. Furthermore, you can override the function call operator to get the exact syntax you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  What you can do is overload the `operator()` of the class to turn it into a functor.  You can add

```
int operator()(int val) { return add(val); }
```

To the class and now `sum(some_value)` is the same thing as `sum.add(some_value)`

Comment: Great! Is it also possible to lose the `()` in case the function does not need a parameter? I mean instead of `myResult = sum()` simply `myResult = sum`?

Comment: @Combinatix Well you could provide a conversion operator that would make your type into something else.  like `operator int() { return v_; }`.  and then you could use that like `int foo = sum;`

Answer (score 2):

That's specifically what the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator) is for.

```
class Sum{
public:
    void value(int val){ _v = val; }
    int add(int val) const{ return _v + val; }

    // Function call operator
    int operator()(int val) const {
        return add(val);
    }

private:
    int _v;
};

int main()
{
    Sum sum;
    sum.value(5);

    // Calls the function call operator
    int myResult = sum(10);
}
```